# Comfortable editor for FAR F2 menu?

Tags: far-manager

It is bad to edit Far's F2 menu by means of Far itself. One need to enter each entry, enter explicit add/remove/edit commands, add title and commands in separate windows with poor copy/paste capabilities.

Is there any tool to edit these menus in entire, for example, by editing some XML file or something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd> (in the menu) and edit your whole menu in the Far editor.